# Xcode 4 installation:

Tags: ios, ios4, xcode4

I just got a Mac OS X 10.7 and was all set to install Xcode 4 and the iOS SDK onto it, but as it turns out, it will not let me do this because the installer reads this:

iPhone SDK requires MAC OS X 10.6.6 (To install iOS SDK you  must quit the installer and upgrade).

What does the SDK mean I should upgrade, my Mac pro is a higher level, it's a 10.7 !!! Do they mean I should downgrade ??? (pun intended!)

Anybody with similar problems and have a way around this?

:(

Parijat Kalia!

Answer (score 1):

Lion requires XCode 4.1 at minimum.